# Limit of a series to produce an analytic function

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

I am writing to find a proof or counter-example of the following statement:

Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}(\varepsilon) z^{n}$ be an analytic function around $z=0$, where $a_{n}(\varepsilon)$ is some sequence of numbers which depends on $\varepsilon$. If the limit, 
\begin{equation} \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \left(a_{0}(\varepsilon) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}(\varepsilon)z^{n}\right) \end{equation}
 exists and is an analytic function of $z$ for $z$ belonging to some sector at $0$ (for example $\left\{0<|z|<\frac{1}{2}, \ 0 < \text{arg}(x) < \frac{\pi}{5}\right\}$ or something, it doesn't matter), then the limit,
\begin{equation} \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(\varepsilon)z^{n} \end{equation}
exists and is an analytic function of $z$ on the same sector.

To me, it feels so intuitively clear because: (1) $a_{0}(\varepsilon)$ does not depend on $z$ so it has no right to affect the analyticity of anything; and (2) we are taking a limit of a series in $z$, so it shouldn't make a difference if we neglect the first term.

I'm sorry I can't suggest any direction of proof, everything I've tried has lead to a dead-end. Thanks for all help!

p.s. I'm convinced I am close to a truth here, if the statement needs adjusting slightly to make it correct then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexmple: For each $\epsilon >0,$ we can do the following:  Let

$$A_\epsilon = \{|z|\le \epsilon\},\,\,B_\epsilon= \{re^{it}: 2\epsilon\le r\le 1, t \in [0,2\pi-\epsilon]\}.$$

By Runge's theorem, there is a polynomial $p_\epsilon$ such that

$$|p_\epsilon | < \epsilon \text { on } A_\epsilon, \,\, |p_\epsilon - \sin(1/\epsilon)| < \epsilon \text { on } B_\epsilon.$$

Now for some reason you don't like mere polynomials. We can satisfy your preference as follows: For $\epsilon>0,$ define

$$f_\epsilon(z) = -\sin(1/\epsilon) + p_\epsilon(z) + e^z.$$

Then for any $z, 0 < |z|<1,$

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}f_\epsilon(z)= e^z,$$

while the limit of $f_\epsilon(z)-f_\epsilon(0)$ fails to exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a bit confused about the relationship between  $\epsilon$ and $n$, where is $\epsilon$ on the rhs of $f_{\eps}(z)$? For my question $\epsilon$ and $n$ should be independent, namely there are 2 limits; a counterexample should produce a polynomial $f_{\eps,n}(z)$ such that: (1)$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_{\eps,n}(z)$ exists and is is analytic, (2) $\lim_{\eps \rightarrow 0} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{\eps,n}(z)$ exists and is analytic (on a sector) but (3) $\lim_{\eps \rightarrow 0} \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} f_{\eps,n}(z)-f_{\eps,n}(0)$ doesn't exist / not analytic

Comment: I don't get how $|p_m | < 1/m \text { on } A_m, \,\, |p_m - (-1)^{m}| < 1/m \text { on } B_m.$ is obtained by Runge's theorem, what is the holomorphic function you are approximating ?

Comment: @reuns We can find disjoint open sets $U_m,V_m$ containing $A_m,B_m$ respectively. The function that equals $0$ on $U_m$ and $(-1)^m$ on $B_m$ is holomorphic on $U_m\cup V_m.$ Because $S^2\setminus (A_m\cup B_m)$ is connected, Runge says there is a polynomial $p_m$ with the claimed properties.

Comment: We need a polynomial that is $\approx 0$ on $A$ and $\approx 1$ on $B$, do you know how to make that ? (and don't we need rational functions instead ?)

Comment: @reuns What are $A,B$?

Comment: @analytic I changed $n$ to $m.$

Comment: $A,B$ are your $A_m,B_m$ for some $m$ or two disjoint unit disks if it is easier.

Comment: @reuns The answer then is yes, you can do that with a polynomial (the sphere minus the set has only one component, which contains $\infty$, which can be taken to be the only pole of the rational function, which implies a polynomial).

Comment: How would you do it concretely ? All I know is $f(z) =\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_\gamma \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds \approx f_L(z) = \frac{1}{2i\pi L}\sum_{l=1}^L \frac{f(\gamma(l/L)\gamma'(l/L)}{\gamma(l/L)-z}$ which works if $\gamma$ encloses two separated simply connected domains $A,B$ and $f$ is holomorphic on $\overline{A \cup B}$ and the convergence is uniform on compacts $\Omega \subset A \cup B$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But again, I'm confused because epsilon and n (or 'm') should be independent: there are two consecutive limits in my question. I'm considering a limit of a limit and your counterexample doesn't seem to fit that, or am I reading it wrong

Comment: @analytic Do you agree that $q_m\to 0$ pointwise on $\{0<|z|<1\},$ and that $q_m-q_m(0)$ diverges point wise there?

Comment: I think I can agree with these. But is it clear to you that $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{m} a_{n}(\varepsilon)z^{-n}$ is not the same as $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{m} a_{n}(\frac{1}{m}) z^{-n}$? My question related to the former while your counterexample seems to fit the latter... apologies again if I am missing something in your explanation

Comment: @analytic But then let $f_{1/m}(z) = q_m(z).$ Through this sequence of $\epsilon$'s, we have pointwise convergence to $0$ everywhere in $\{0<|z|<1\}.$ But $f_{1/m}(z)-f_{1/m}(0)$ converges for no $z$ in this set. Each $f_{1/m}(z)$ has a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(1/m)z^n.$ And each $f_{1/m}(z)-f_{1/m}(0)$ is precisely $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(1/m)z^n.$

Comment: I thought $q_{m}(z) ( =: f_{\frac{1}{m}}(z))$ is a polynomial, what do you mean by "Each $f_{\frac{1}{m}}(z)$ has a power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}(\frac{1}{m})z^{n}$"?

Comment: @analytic  Come now, I'm just putting the thing in your terms. Polynomials have power series expansions you know.

Comment: So, putting your example into my terms, you mean to say that $a_{n}(\frac{1}{m}):=0$ for $n >m$ ? I'm afraid that isn't a series, it's a polynomial. I can accept that your counterexample fits the criteria for a particular case of my question, namely for considering limits of polynomials, so I thank you for that. However, I cannot accept that my question is fully answered.

Comment: @analytic You think $z+z^3$ is not a power series?

Comment: $z + z^{3}$ is a polynomial. I know you want to say, "but $z+z^{3} \equiv z + z^{3} + \sum_{n=4}^{\infty} 0 \times z^{n}$". It is a matter of common sense that a power series is a sum of infinite terms whose terms are, in general, non-zero. For example, you wouldn't call $z + z^{3}$ a linear combination of polynomials and circular functions, even though $z + z^{3} \equiv z + z^{3} + 0 \times \sin(z)$. In any case, when I wrote "the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(\eps)z^{n}$" in my question I definitely did not mean to allow the trivial possibility that $a_{n}(\eps) = 0$ for $n>$ some $m$.

Comment: @analytic There's nothing trivial in my solution. I've solved your problem, even with your new demand that all power series not be finite sums. Just consider $q_m(z) + e^z.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry to have a long string of comments, my main problem is that your $\varepsilon$ and $m$ are not independent, which I raised in my first comment. My question is concerned with two limits of the form $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} F(m,\varepsilon)$ which is not equivalent to just taking one limit of the form $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} F( \frac{1}{\varepsilon}, \varepsilon)$. If you can explain whether your answer covers this then I may concede.

Comment: @analytic I've never undertood your point here. I've edited my answer; I hope it helps; it's my last gasp.